# Stuck Deploying my first app engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-php

I am deploying my first app to google app engine and I am getting stuck at "Started cloud build" obviously there is some kind of problem with the build but I am unsure how to diagnose or proceed.

I have included the LOG file if that helps

```
    2017-05-25 17:13:32,680 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'app']
2017-05-25 17:13:32,864 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'app', 'deploy']
2017-05-25 17:13:32,865 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: []
2017-05-25 17:13:33,016 DEBUG    root            API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1]
2017-05-25 17:13:34,256 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ You are about to deploy the following services:

2017-05-25 17:13:34,257 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  - single-quanta-158320/default/20170525t171334 (from [D:\Path Redacted\app.yaml])
     Deploying to URL: [https://URL Redacted]


2017-05-25 17:17:26,509 DEBUG    root            No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
2017-05-25 17:17:26,512 DEBUG    root            Using bucket [gs://Redacted].
2017-05-25 17:17:26,512 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...
2017-05-25 17:17:26,513 DEBUG    root            Host: appengine.google.com
2017-05-25 17:17:26,519 DEBUG    googlecloudsdk.third_party.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
2017-05-25 17:17:26,520 DEBUG    googlecloudsdk.third_party.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/vms/prepare?app_id=Redacted headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=
2017-05-25 17:17:26,520 INFO     oauth2client.transport Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
2017-05-25 17:17:26,520 INFO     oauth2client.client Refreshing access_token
2017-05-25 17:17:31,799 DEBUG    root            Got response: {bucket: vm-containers.Redacted.appspot.com, path: /containers}

2017-05-25 17:17:31,805 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2017-05-25 17:17:32,040 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Beginning deployment of service [default]...

2017-05-25 17:17:32,042 DEBUG    root            No staging command found for runtime [php] and environment [FLEX].
2017-05-25 17:17:32,042 INFO     root            Need Dockerfile to be generated for runtime php
2017-05-25 17:17:32,042 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Building and pushing image for service [default]

2017-05-25 17:17:32,121 INFO     root            Not checking for [Custom] because runtime is [php]
2017-05-25 17:17:32,121 INFO     root            Not checking for [Go] because runtime is [php]
2017-05-25 17:17:32,122 INFO     root            Not checking for [Ruby] because runtime is [php]
2017-05-25 17:17:32,122 INFO     root            Not checking for [Node.js] because runtime is [php]
2017-05-25 17:17:32,122 INFO     root            Not checking for [Java] because runtime is [php]
2017-05-25 17:17:32,122 INFO     root            Not checking for [Python Compat] because runtime is [php]
2017-05-25 17:17:32,122 INFO     root            Not checking for [Python] because runtime is [php]
2017-05-25 17:17:32,167 INFO     root            Not writing [app.yaml], it already exists.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,190 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [.git]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,190 INFO     root            Ignoring file [.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,190 INFO     root            Ignoring file [.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,193 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/webmozart/assert/.composer-auth.json]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,193 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/webmozart/assert/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,193 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/webmozart/assert/.styleci.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,194 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/webmozart/assert/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,194 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/torann/currency/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,194 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/torann/currency/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,194 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/torann/currency/tests/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,197 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/yaml/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,197 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/var-dumper/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,200 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/translation/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,207 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/routing/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,214 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/process/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,217 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/http-kernel/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,233 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/http-foundation/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,237 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Tests/File/Fixtures/.unknownextension]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,239 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Tests/File/Fixtures/directory/.empty]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,240 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/finder/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,244 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,246 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,247 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/debug/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,250 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/css-selector/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,256 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/symfony/console/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,269 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,269 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,269 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/.php_cs.dist]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,269 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,292 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/shpasser/gae-support-l5/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,292 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/shpasser/gae-support-l5/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,292 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/shpasser/gae-support-l5/tests/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,295 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/version/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,295 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/version/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,296 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/recursion-context/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,296 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/recursion-context/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,296 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/global-state/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,296 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/global-state/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,298 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/exporter/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,298 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/exporter/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,299 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/environment/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,299 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/environment/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,299 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/diff/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,299 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/diff/.php_cs]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,299 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/diff/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,301 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/comparator/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,301 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/sebastian/comparator/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,305 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/psy/psysh/.editorconfig]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,305 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/psy/psysh/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,306 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [vendor/psy/psysh/.phan]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,306 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/psy/psysh/.php_cs]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,306 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/psy/psysh/.styleci.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,306 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/psy/psysh/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,308 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/psy/psysh/test/fixtures/project/.psysh.php]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,308 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [vendor/psy/psysh/test/fixtures/mixed/.psysh]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,308 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [vendor/psy/psysh/test/fixtures/legacy/.psysh]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,308 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [vendor/psy/psysh/test/fixtures/default/.config]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,309 INFO     root            Ignoring directory [vendor/psy/psysh/test/fixtures/default/.local]: Directory matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,318 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/psr/log/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,319 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,319 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,319 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,325 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/phpunit/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,325 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/phpunit/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,325 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/phpunit/.php_cs]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,325 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/phpunit/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,351 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,351 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,351 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,352 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-timer/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,352 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-timer/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,352 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-timer/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,354 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-text-template/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,354 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-text-template/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,354 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,354 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,355 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,355 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,355 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,361 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpspec/prophecy/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,362 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpspec/prophecy/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,414 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpdocumentor/type-resolver/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,414 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpdocumentor/type-resolver/.scrutinizer.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,414 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpdocumentor/type-resolver/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,415 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,415 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock/.scrutinizer.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,415 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,421 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phpdocumentor/reflection-common/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,421 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phenx/php-svg-lib/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,421 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phenx/php-svg-lib/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,421 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phenx/php-svg-lib/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,424 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,424 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,424 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/.htaccess]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,428 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/nikic/php-parser/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,428 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/nikic/php-parser/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,450 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/nesbot/carbon/.php_cs.dist]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,453 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/mtdowling/cron-expression/.editorconfig]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,453 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/monolog/monolog/.php_cs]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,457 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/monolog/monolog/tests/Monolog/Handler/Fixtures/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,463 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/mockery/mockery/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,463 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/mockery/mockery/.php_cs]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,463 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/mockery/mockery/.scrutinizer.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,463 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/mockery/mockery/.styleci.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,463 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/mockery/mockery/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,470 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/mockery/mockery/docs/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,471 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,471 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,473 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar/tests/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,476 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/league/flysystem/docs/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,522 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,522 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,523 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/jakub-onderka/php-console-color/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,523 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/jakub-onderka/php-console-color/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,525 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/.coveralls.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,525 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,525 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/.gush.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,525 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,535 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,536 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/fzaninotto/faker/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,536 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/fzaninotto/faker/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,566 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/flynsarmy/db-blade-compiler/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,566 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/flynsarmy/db-blade-compiler/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,566 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/flynsarmy/db-blade-compiler/tests/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,568 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/flynsarmy/db-blade-compiler/config/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,568 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/dompdf/dompdf/.gitattributes]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,568 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/dompdf/dompdf/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,568 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/dompdf/dompdf/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,575 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/instantiator/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,575 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/instantiator/.scrutinizer.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,575 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/instantiator/.travis.install.sh]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,575 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/instantiator/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,578 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/inflector/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,578 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/inflector/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,598 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/cache/.coveralls.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,598 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/cache/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,598 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/doctrine/cache/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,602 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,604 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/cmgmyr/messenger/.php_cs]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,605 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/cmgmyr/messenger/src/migrations/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,605 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/cmgmyr/messenger/src/config/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,608 INFO     root            Ignoring file [vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,608 INFO     root            Ignoring file [storage/framework/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,609 INFO     root            Ignoring file [storage/framework/sessions/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,611 INFO     root            Ignoring file [storage/framework/cache/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,611 INFO     root            Ignoring file [storage/app/db-blade-compiler/views/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,622 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/.htaccess]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,644 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/phpmyadmin/test/.htaccess]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,723 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/phpmyadmin/js/jquery/src/jquery-ui/.jshintrc]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,724 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/phpmyadmin/js/jquery/src/jquery/.jshintrc]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,733 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/phpmyadmin/doc/html/.buildinfo]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,743 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/formbuilder/css/.DS_Store]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,743 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/formbuilder/css/._.DS_Store]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,743 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/formbuilder/css/lib/.DS_Store]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,743 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/formbuilder/css/lib/._.DS_Store]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,743 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/formbuilder/css/lib/bootstrap-3.0.0/.editorconfig]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,743 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/formbuilder/css/lib/bootstrap-3.0.0/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,743 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/formbuilder/css/lib/bootstrap-3.0.0/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,769 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/bfb/assets/._.DS_Store]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,773 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/bfb/assets/css/._.DS_Store]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,773 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/bfb/assets/css/lib/._.DS_Store]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,773 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/bfb/assets/css/lib/bootstrap-3.0.0/.editorconfig]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,773 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/bfb/assets/css/lib/bootstrap-3.0.0/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,773 INFO     root            Ignoring file [public/includes/bfb/assets/css/lib/bootstrap-3.0.0/.travis.yml]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,776 INFO     root            Ignoring file [database/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,776 INFO     root            Ignoring file [database/seeds/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,780 INFO     root            Ignoring file [database/migrations/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,785 INFO     root            Ignoring file [bootstrap/cache/.gitignore]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,786 INFO     root            Ignoring file [app/Policies/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,788 INFO     root            Ignoring file [app/Listeners/.gitkeep]: File matches ignore regex.
2017-05-25 17:17:59,790 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Some files were skipped. Pass `--verbosity=info` to see which ones.

2017-05-25 17:17:59,790 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ You may also view the gcloud log file, found at
[C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2017.05.25\17.13.32.677000.log].

2017-05-25 17:18:34,349 INFO     root            Uploading [d:\temp\temp\tmpewz3oo\src.tgz] to [us.gcr.io/Redacted/appengine/default.20170525t171334:latest]
2017-05-25 17:19:04,826 DEBUG    root            Using builder image: [gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker]
2017-05-25 17:19:06,588 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Started cloud build [50fd916b-cbff-4f40-8404-aa9a961f8206].
```

Comment: Can you give us a more in depth explanation of the steps you have taken so far?

Comment: The reporter said it's solved in a comment on the one of the answers below. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

From your log file, I see that you're deploying a PHP application to the App Engine flexible environment.

It looks like "gcloud app deploy" has gotten stuck trying to start the container build for your application.  I tried the same thing locally, and in my case the log file continued like this after "Started cloud build":

```
2017-05-25 15:15:46,138 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Started cloud build [BUILD-ID-REDACTED].

2017-05-25 15:15:46,142 DEBUG    root            GCS logfile url is https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/staging.APP-ID-REDACTED.appspot.com/o/log-BUILD-ID-REDACTED.txt?alt=media
2017-05-25 15:15:46,143 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ To see logs in the Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/BUILD-ID-REDACTED?project=APP-ID-REDACTED

2017-05-25 15:15:46,417 DEBUG    root            Operation [operations/build/APP-ID-REDACTED/OPERATION-ID-REDACTED] not complete. Waiting 1s.
2017-05-25 15:15:48,073 DEBUG    root            Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 227 bytes)
2017-05-25 15:15:48,074 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is an odd place for it to stop.  Was there any relevant console output at the time?

What happens if you retry the "gcloud app deploy" command?  Does it get any further?

Comment: Managed to find the build logs in google app engine, turns out the build was hanging on a PHP dependency my application needed but was not included by default. adding that extension sorted the issue

Comment: Can you close the question?

Answer (score 0):

It really does seem like your log file is cut off here.  There may be a difference between the gcloud console output and the log file located at `C:\Users\Redacted\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2017.05.25\17.13.32.677000.log`

(I've noticed that gcloud can stop outputting to the console if you scroll up, but pressing the down arrow fixes this.)